# First Use case diagram for test application

Tags: uml, use-case

[image]Hello,

I am developing a test application for an electric motor, which will ultimately be written in LabVIEW, and I am using SysML modelling to define the system.  The use case diagram attached is my top level.

The start Test Scenario task is dependant on Initialise System completing successfully, is it right that this should be connected to the Actor.

Could anyone advise if this is a good approach (I'm hoping to develop my LV Front Panel controls from this).

If anyone can suggest improvements, it would be appreciated.

Thanks 
Dave

Answer (score 0):

The actor should be connected to the operation he does, in this case, start test scenario. Since you `<<include>>` initialize system from it, it makes it dependent. So you should change your actor's connection to start case scenario

Comment: I see, so I dont have to directly connect the Initialise system case because of its dependancy?

Comment: No, and you need to transfer the connection from the author to the start test scenario

Comment: These answers are sintatically correct but semantically wrong, since the own diagram is wrong itself. For example, Use Cases should not represent tasks (as you called) but functionalities, they should also  return some "value" to the user, and many other characteristics. The diagram that you posted has some mistakes and should be rewriten based on the requirements specification, not on the implementation you expect to do for your project.